# Measuring the string width in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to precisely fit a string into a certain width. This means the font-size changes depending on the string. I now use the following function, using jQuery:

```
function fontResize ( )
{
    for (var i = $("#date").css("font-size").slice(0, -2); $("#date").width() < $("#clock").width(); i++)
        $("#date").css("font-size", i.toString() + "px");   
}
```

The idea is that I set the font-size in the CSS to the lowest possible value. I initialize the  loop with this value and increment the font-size with 1 until the string is wider than the width of the containing element. The string in this case is "date" and the containing element is "clock".

Although this works, I think the main disadvantage is that the string has to be first drawn before the width can be determined. This means I cannot call this function before loading the body.

If anyone knows a better way to do this please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure you're getting all the styles and such applied to it that will be applied when the page is fully rendered, yes, you do want to put the element in the DOM (and in the right place in the DOM) before you do your measurement stuff. But you don't have to wait until everything *else* is there (unless you think it will affect the styling of the string you're measuring). You can put your code in a `script` block *immediately* after the element in question — no waiting for `ready`. The `date` element will be there and accessible, according to [Google's Closure library engineers](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41). E.g., if `date` is a `span`:

```
<body>
...
<span id="date">December 13th</span>
<script>fontResize();</script>
...
...
</body>
```

It's unfortunate to intermix code and markup like that (particularly if you have separate teams doing the markup and the code), but if your requirement is to size the text absolutely as soon as possible, that's how.

The above also assumes your `fontResize` function is already loaded (e.g., in a `script` block higher on the page). This is another reason it's unfortunate to mix markup and code like this, because normally of course you want to put your scripts [at the bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), just before closing the `body` tag.

**However**: It may be worth experimenting to see if you can do your resizing in the script you put just before the closing `body` tag instead. There'd be a small window of opportunity for the page not to look right, but quite small and of course pages tend to look a little funny as they load anyway. Then you wouldn't have the intermixing problem and wouldn't have to load your scripts early. You may find that the just-before-the-closing-`body`-tag is soon enough.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Since I'm using a background image (which takes considerably more time to load) I decided it would best if I could get the text to load with the image (feels less cheap). Putting all the functions after "onload" seems to have done the trick. If I understand it correctly the functions after "unload" are only called when the whole page is loaded. So that should make sense.

Comment: @KeyMs92: Yes, the `load` event is fired ***very*** late in the page load cycle, right at the end, when all resources have been loaded. If that's early enough for you, great, but if not you could always create an `img` element referencing the background image (without adding it to the DOM) and watch its `load` event, so you could act as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the canvas, and the measureText method?

```
    $(function () {
        var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var text = "hello world";
        context.font = "40pt Calibri";
        var metrics = context.measureText(text);
        alert(metrics.width);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also know a way to eliminate the use of a loop to get the font size? The loop seems to take a considerable amount of time, especially when it's initialized with low values.